# Call multiple return functions in Laravel function

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel, I currently have a working function that accepts arguments, uses them in a stored procedure, and then creates a variable from the output of the procedure to be used in another function call. The variable in question is $out2, and when the process is successful, it calls the function createUser with that variable.

```
function createMainUser($firstName,$lastName){

    $stmt = \DB::connection('odbc')->getPdo()->prepare('CALL procedure.create_user(?,?,?)'); 

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $firstName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $lastName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $out2, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();

    return $this->createUser($out2,$firstName,$lastName);

}
```

Everything here works perfectly. However, I'm wondering if I can call multiple functions with that `$out2` variable. So when `createMainuser` runs and is successful, thus creating `$out2` I'd like to keep doing what I'm doing now with the return, but I'd also like to call a function called `tempUserRecord` with `$out2`.

Is that something I can adequately do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm understanding your question wrongly, but this seems rather easy?

```
$userCreated = $this->createUser($out2,$firstName,$lastName);

if ($userCreated) {  // Depends on what "createUser" returns
    $this->tempUserRecord($out2); // Might not be "$this"
}

return $userCreated;
```

Or run `tempUserRecords()` in the function where you call `createMainUser()`.

Comment: I think your first portion there will work. The other option won't because I only get $out2 inside the createMainuser function. But that makes sense with the if statement, I think